# Form in HTML with button assigns the value of the last button, no matter which one was selected

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, radio-button

I want to create a form with HTML with different types of inputs (such as name, surname, dates, and radio-button options), and when I want to print the object with the data inputted in the form on the console, the value from the radio-buttons is not stored correctly.

First of all, this is my first project on this area and also my first posted question on stackoverflow, so I would appreciate some suggestions on how to pose the question better if I'm forgetting some crucial data.

I have been following help from different resources (mostly youtube videos such as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrycH6F-ksY ) to create this form and submit the data with AJAX, and the code of my javascript application comes mainly from that video.

All the data is stored correctly and I can see it in the console, except from the data comming from the radio-buttons. No matter what option is selected (either "male" or "female"), the console always shows the value of the last button, which in this case is "female". I suppose I am doing something wrong when defining these buttons, and why they are not being "selected" (I suppose that's what is happening since the data shown is always the last default value) but I haven't been able to find out where I am doing something wrong.

I'm including the part of the code that I think might be relevant

```
<form action="ajax/contact.php" method="post" class="ajax">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Surname</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSurname" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date of birth</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inputDate">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Gender</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <div class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inputGender" 
value="male">Male</div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <div class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inputGender"  
value="female">Female</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Number of children</label>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="inputNumber">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="text-center">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

---

Javascript function

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

  var that = $(this),
  url = that.attr('action'),
  method = that.attr('method'),
  data = {};

  that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
    var that = $(this),
    name = that.attr('name'),
    value = that.val();

    data[name] = value;
  });

  console.log(data);


  return false;
});
```

---

PHP file

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['inputName'],$_POST['inputSurname'],$_POST['inputDate'],$_POST['inputEmail'],$_POST['inputGender'],$_POST['inputNumber'])) {
print_r($_POST);
}
```

In the console I'm getting this:

```
${inputName: "myName", inputSurname: "mySurname", inputDate: "2019-12-13", 
$inputEmail: "myMail@gmail.com", inputGender: "female", …}
$inputDate: "2019-12-13"
$inputEmail: "myMail@gmail.com"
$inputGender: "female"
$inputName: "myName"
$inputNumber: "1"
$inputSurname: "mySurname"
$_proto_: Object
```

but I thought it would be showing:

```
$...
$inputGender: "male"
$...
```

when the male option is selected.

Thank you very much

Comment: did you try add one more as first order <input type="radio" name="inputGender" 
value="Non Specific" style="display:none"></div>

- Non Specifi (Not display *CSS)
- Male
- Female

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your JS. You're looping through everything with a `name` attribute, in order, and adding its value to your submit data. In the case of radio buttons, you have to check if they're selected and only add if so, otherwise, the last one always wins, as you're seeing.

And since you appear to be using jQuery, you can probably just let its [serialize helper](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) do this work for you.